# Fixing an almost valid JSON file

Tags: python, json

I have the following JSON data.(It is not a fully valid data.But it is almost valid)

```
{
    u'Category': u'Exp',
    u'Severity': u'warn',
    u'EventName': u'TimeExceeded',
    u'EventTimestamp': u'1432510367083',
    u'Message': u'details: {
        "Message": "long (2567 ms : ATime: 5 ms, BTime: 1237 ms, CTime: 1325 ms)",
        "Title": "Core Herald influence",
        "Referrer": "undefined",
        "Time": "Mon May 25 2015 11:32:47 GMT+1200 (NZST)",
        "Session": "None",
        "ResponseTime": 0,
        "StatusCode": 0,
        "Links": 325,
        "Images": 57,
        "Forms": 2,
        "Errors": 0,
        "Platform": "Linux x86_64",
        "BrowserAppname": "Netscape",
        "AppCodename": "Mozilla",
        "Product": "Gecko",
        "CPUs": 8,
        "Language": "en-GB",

    }',
    u'Subject': u'TimeExceeded'
}
```

My questions are the following.
I see `u` in a few places in the data as 
`u'Category'` and `u'Exp'` above. What does those mean exactly?

How do I convert the above data to a valid JSON ?

Comment: `u` means its a unicode object

Comment: Do you have the original dictionary object? Or is this data in a file?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso - how do I change that to a non-unicode object ? if that is a thing. The idea is that I should be able to access the members in the strucutre.

Comment: @AliGajani - you mean for induvudual fields?

Comment: You should not change that to a non-unicode object, you should serialize the dict full of unicode objects with `json.dump` or `jump.dumps` instead of `print` or `str` or `repr`.

Comment: `u'Message': u'details: {` is invalid to python object or JSON.

Comment: @YOU but that whole inner dictionary is contained in a string (although I guess not a triple-quoted multiline string). It's hard to tell how this is being produced, maybe someone has come up with an output function that pretty-prints each field before storing them in the dict?

Answer (score 7):

Although they look similar, this is actually not JSON, but Python's representation of a dict if you print it.

There are two reasons this is invalid:

1. The `u` which represents `unicode` in front of each string
2. You need double-quotes around your keys and values in JSON, not single-quotes.

Assuming you have a representation of the `dict` object in Python, you should serialize it to JSON via the json module:

```
import json

d = {u'x': 5}
print json.dumps(d)
> {"x": 5}  # notice the double-quotes
```

Some background on the `u`:

In Python 2.x, strings were either of 8-bit string type or Unicode. To differentiate between the two, a `u` is placed in front of Unicode strings. In JSON, a string is solely defined as "a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters". There is no need to differentiate between different string types.

Answer (score 2):

If you actually have this `dict` in Python, and you just want to know how to generate valid JSON from it, you do that with the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module. See [Martin Konecny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30429538/908494) for details.

If, on the other hand, you have this text in a file somewhere, and it's too late to store it properly, you just need to get it back into a `dict`, the only reasonable way to reverse the effects of calling `repr` or `str` (or just `print`) on a Python object is to call [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). This only works if the thing that you `print`ed is made up of nothing but a handful of very basic types… but that seems to be the case here.

Again, you should *only* do this if you don't have the data in a better format, and can't re-create it. But if that's the case, there's no better option.

So, for example, the following program will print out `TimeExceeded`:

```
import ast

not_json = """
{
    u'Category': u'Exp',
    u'Severity': u'warn',
    # ... [snip] ...
    u'Subject': u'TimeExceeded'
}
"""

d = ast.literal_eval(not_json)
print(d[u'Subject'])
```